# Lower bound of $n$ and $\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have found the below information regarding lower bounds of $n$ and $\frac{1}{n}$:

Lower bound of $n$ is $1$

Some of the Lower bounds of $\frac{1}{n}\,$ are $\,0 ,-2\,$ where as $0$ is the greatest lower bound.

My question is: 1) Is $1$ the greatest lower bound for $n$? Are there other lower bounds apart from $1$ like the negative numbers in case of $\frac{1}{n}$

2)Why is $1$ is the lower bound for $n$ whereas $0$ is the lower bound for $\frac{1}{n}$? Why not its the same lower bound in both the cases?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: $0$ is a lower bound for $n$, but it isn't the greatest one.

Comment: Consider reading the definition for lower bound and greatest lower bound again.  Continue by noticing that $-1<n$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ and that $-1<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z^+$.  Continue by noticing that $1\geq\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ and that $1$ is not less than for example $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, $1$ is the greatest lower bound. Of course, $-\frac12$, $0$ or $-\pi$ are also lower bounds.
2. Why should it be the same? $0\leqslant\frac1n$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$ and therefore $0$ is a lower bound. It is not hard to prove that it is the greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

To add to **Jose**'s answer, consider the image below. The blue points and line represent the curve $y=n$, while the red points and line represent $y=\frac1n$. Let's shade, in blue, everywhere on the plane below the blue curve. In other words, we're finding a lower bound. Of course the lowest blue point is at $(1,1)$, so there we go, everything below $y=1$ can be shaded blue. Hence, $n\geq1$. But we could also have made this shaded region slightly lower, say at $y=-2$ since our only rule is that the blue line is above the shaded area. This means it's correct to say $n\geq1$ or $n>-2$ or even $n>-10$.

But let's to shade, in red, the plane below the red curve. We've got to shade below $(1,1)$ because we know that $(2,0.5)$ is a point. But also, $(10,0.1)$ and $(100,0.01)$ and so on. Clearly, as $n$ gets larger, $\frac1n$ gets closer to $0$. Hence, $\frac1n>0$.

[image: n and 1/n]